# Canvas-LMS - LoadError: cannot load such file -- parallel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu-12.04, rvm-capistrano, canvas-lms

Working on deploying the canvas to a server and when i run the command RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake canvas:compile_assets i get an error :

`LoadError: cannot load such file -- parallel
/var/www/prod/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/polyglot-0.3.5/lib/polyglot.rb:65:in`require'
/var/www/prod/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/polyglot-0.3.5/lib/polyglot.rb:65:in `require'
/var/www/prod/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in`block in require'
/var/www/prod/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/var/www/prod/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in`require'
/var/www/prod/releases/20141215031227/lib/tasks/canvas.rake:114:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => canvas:compile_assets`

Checked gem list for the parallel gem, checked to confirmed bundle install was completed without error. Checked the gemset, permissions, what else should i look into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we found out that bundler was not installing gems that we needed and that caused the problem. since we deployed with Capistrano we set the `set :bundle_without, "nil"`. OR you can modify the config file to remove the bundle_without line. We ran `bundle install --deployment --without test development` because we were deploying to production.